# Windows API error 1392 using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, miktex, hyphenation

When I compile the following very M(N)WE with `pdflatex` I get the error message

```
pdflatex: Windows API error 1392: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
pdflatex: Data: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic\dehyph-exptl

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Sun Mar 01 11:09:12
```

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
Hello, world
\end{document}
```

When I comment out `\usepackage{hyperref}` compilation is OK. It's also OK with
`\usepackage[draft]{hyperref}`. Explicitly asking for `\usepackage[pdftex]{hyperref}` doesn't help.

This started happening several days ago; there has been no change I know of to my environment.

**Edit.** The same Windows error occurs when I try to compile a more complex document that does not use `hyperref`. Some other package is probably calling for file

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic\dehyph-exptl
```

Here's (most of) the terminal output for the example above. I can provide the full log file if that would help.

```
-*- mode: compilation; default-directory: "~/tex/" -*-
Compilation started at Sun Mar 01 11:14:07

pdflatex error1392
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(c:\eb\tex\error1392.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ...
welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-hyperref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\hobsub-generic.sty"))
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\ifxetex\ifxetex.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\auxhook.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\kvoptions.sty")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\pd1enc.def")
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\hyperref.cfg")
(C:\Users\eb\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\url\url.sty))

Package hyperref Message: Driver (autodetected): hpdftex.

("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\hpdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\oberdiek\rerunfilecheck.sty"))
(c:\eb\tex\error1392.aux)
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\hyperref\nameref.sty"
("C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek
 \gettitlestring.sty"))
 pdflatex: Windows API error 1392: The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.
pdflatex: Data: C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic\dehyph-exptl

Compilation exited abnormally with code 1 at Sun Mar 01 11:14:07
```

Comment: Have you tried opening the directory in Explorer? This is likely not a TeX problem but just good old fashioned file system corruption or a dying hard drive. I suggest you backup any important data on that disk *immediately*. "Windows API Error" indicates that the error value came from Windows and not from within TeX. Other applications experience this too: https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+api+%22error+1392%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: @kahen Right on. Folder wouldn't open. Uninstalled miktex (had to rename the miktex home since it couldn't be deleted) and reinstalled. Will hope problem doesn't recur. (I backed up when I first saw the error, and have done so frequently since.) Post your comment as an answer so I can accept it.